# PageNotFound - Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, api

I am getting this error while calling an API from postman, after I hosted my spring app in VM. Locally it works. But Get methods in my VMs are working.

[http-nio-8081-exec-4] PageNotFound - Request method 'GET' not supported

My controller method looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders/")
public class OrdersController {}

@PostMapping(value = "create", produces = "text/plain")
private String createOrder(@RequestBody POCreationRequest request) throws ParseException {
```

The API request running forever and dont get any response. I found the exception in my log. Any idea on this issue?

Comment: Can you post the requested URl and the error in response as well.

Comment: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/orders/create.
I am not getting any response. Postman is running forever.  I found the error I posted is from my logs.

Comment: The issue is you have mapped your URL /orders/create to a post mapping. But you are requesting a get mapping. So that you got that error.  Please change your request URL.

Comment: No. In postman, I am making post request only.

Comment: In VM are you using browser or postman ?

Comment: no my app is hosted in azure VM but i am making this call from my local desktop using postman.

Comment: just another finding, if i deliberately send any wrong values in my request body, I am getting exception as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You created two urls there:

- url/orders/ -> accepts get/post/etc... (though its not implemented)
- url/orders/create -> accepts post

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrdersController {

@PostMapping(value = "create", produces = "text/plain")
  private String createOrder(@RequestBody POCreationRequest request) throws ParseException {
System.out.println(request)}
}
```

You can try the above code.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to make a `GET` request on an only `POST` endpoint, thus then not loading the page. Your endpoint should be of type `GET`. You can also have the same endpoint for `GET` and `POST` requests as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders/")
public class OrdersController {}

@PostMapping(value = "create", produces = "text/plain")
private String createOrder(@RequestBody POCreationRequest request) throws ParseException {
    //Parse post requests
}

@GetMapping(value= "create")
private String servePage() {
    return create; //create is the name of the html view.
}
```

Now when going to `localhost:8080/orders/create` it should serve the view.

You can also make the `GET` mapping return a JSON object by:

```
@GetMapping(value= "create")
private String serveJSON() {
    return "{\"hello\": \"world\"}"; //The string is treated as JSON and not as a view.
}
```

Comment: Request body on Get mapping??

Comment: I want this method to be a post method. I am making a call as a post request only from postman

Comment: @user1456110 The error describes that you are trying to make a 'GET' request to a 'POST' endpoint. `Request method 'GET' not supported`